# Windows Store app C# - 2 scrollviewers that scroll depending on the other

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer

Link to image of basic layout I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMtSO.png

Ok so above is a rough diagram of what I want to happen when the user clicks tomorrow I want it to scroll to tomorrows start(12am) location on the scrollview1. Also a similar action while scrolling through scrollview1 would happen(If I scroll past 12am then it should go to the next day on scrollview2). The current section in scrollview2 will be highlighted.
The data is a JSON feed(I cant show too many details as the feed isnt public yet) in which there is data from 12am of today to about 4 days ahead so the scroll is done using C# not hardcoded in XAML. Im open to any other suggestions on how to do this :) .

The response from the feed is stored in a list ready to use.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: I've been looking at ScrollIntoView but really not sure how I would do that. I was thinking about scroll snapPoints but think having trouble thinking about it.

Comment: There will be some interesting logic, a lot synchronizations between the scrollbars, but nothing really special.

Comment: Without code, it is usually hard to guess what the exact problem is, and guessing for answers is usually the only thing anybody can do. If you provide a piece of code of your previous attempts, it will be a lot easier to understand what the exact problem you're having is. That piece of code can even be code that doesn't work at all, because it would still give a better idea of what you are trying to do exactly.